# Build error in jupyterlab using gcp. How to fix?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I use notebook as python in Google AI Platform.
When I open my notebook by clicking Open in JupyterLab, it shows build recommended and I did that.
It shows "Build Failed" and recommend me to run:

```
jupyter lab build
```

[image]

But, as I did `jupyter lab build`, it failed and showed the following:

> [LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 1.2.16
> [LabBuildApp] Building in /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab [LabBuildApp]
> Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize) An error occured.
> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
> '/opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/staging/index.js' See the log file for
> details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-c7f1f1_h.log

I was not able to use extension and fed up with this situation.

Could you tell me how to solve the problem?
(And could you tell me how to open log file in jupyterlab?)

> Hi, Malaman san. Thanks for your answer.

I ran the command "# cat /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-c7f1f1_h.log" and I pasted the results.I don't know how to solve "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted", so could you tell me how to solve that?

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Node v6.13.1

[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 98, in start
    command=command, app_options=app_options)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 459, in build
    command=command, clean_staging=clean_staging)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 650, in build
    clean=clean_staging

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 1103, in _populate_staging
    shutil.copy(pjoin(HERE, 'staging', fname), target)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 249, in copy
    copymode(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 144, in copymode
    chmod_func(dst, stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode))

[LabBuildApp] PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/staging/index.js'

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

Comment: SSH into instance and run: sudo -i, then once as root, run jupyter lab build.

Comment: Can you please share the details of your instance, is it a Python 3, TensorFlow Enterprise 1.15 ...? Did your instance worked in the past? Can you list the labextensions installed? When you say that you got a "build recommended" message, is it because you did some change in the VM?

Answer (score 0):

As you are given an 500 error, it may be due to the following:

- Gateway timeout (504) error. This indicates that the external proxy (the request never reached the Internal inverting proxy server) or the backend server (Jupyter returns a 504 error) timeout. If this is the case, this may be related to memory issues. You can either upgrade your machine or contact Google Cloud support in order to have someone interacting with the Docker proxy agent.
- Timeout occurred (524) error. This indicates that the Inverting Proxy agent isn't connecting to the Inverting Proxy server or the requests are taking too long on the backend server side (Jupyter). If this is the case: verify that the notebook is started and that the disk is not out of space. In order to do so, connect via SSH to the instance and run `df -h -T /home/jupyter`. If the **Use%** is above 85%, manually delete the files from the directory `/home/jupyter`. If it is not the case, please verify that the following services are running: Docker, Inverting Proxy and Jupyter. Try restarting them.

Regarding the logs, SSH into the instance and run the following command:

```
cat /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-c7f1f1_h.log
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.Firstly, I tried to solve Timeout occurred (524) error. As I ran  df -h -T /home/jupyter, the Use% is 22%, so is not above 85%.I executed notebook in JupyterLab, so it seems that Jupyter is running.